# the definition of the char in BMFont file

Tags: bitmap-fonts

```
`char id=52 x=180 y=5 width=50 height=50 xoffset=0 yoffset=0 xadvance=50 page=0 chnl=0`
```

The string above is the definition of char '1'.

I wonder what does the property 'page' and 'chnl' mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BMFont format can be found here

[AngelCode bmfont file format](https://angelcode.com/products/bmfont/doc/file_format.html)

> **page**  The texture page where the character image is found.
> Blockquote
>
> **chnl**  The texture channel where the character image is found (1 = blue, 2 = green, 4 = red, 8 = alpha, 15 = all channels).

**page** is used when the glyphs are spread over multiple images (pages). In the common section in the header of the file you can see the number of pages

> **common**
> **pages** The number of texture pages included in the font.

The channnels (red/green/blue/alpha) can store different information for the glyph.

> **common**
> **packed**    Set to 1 if the monochrome characters have been packed into each of the texture channels. In this case alphaChnl describes what is
> stored in each channel.

> **common**
> **alphaChnl** Set to 0 if the channel holds the glyph data, 1 if it holds
> the outline, 2 if it holds the glyph and the outline, 3 if its set to
> zero, and 4 if its set to one.

> **common**
> **redChnl**   Set to 0 if the channel holds the glyph data, 1 if it holds
> the outline, 2 if it holds the glyph and the outline, 3 if its set to
> zero, and 4 if its set to one.

> **common**
> **greenChnl** Set to 0 if the channel holds the glyph data, 1 if it holds
> the outline, 2 if it holds the glyph and the outline, 3 if its set to
> zero, and 4 if its set to one.

> **common**
> **blueChnl**  Set to 0 if the channel holds the glyph data, 1 if it holds
> the outline, 2 if it holds the glyph and the outline, 3 if its set to
> zero, and 4 if its set to one.